# Render without enconding in cshtml template

Tags: asp.net-core

When I try to render a string in cshtml, it will render with char `&` enconded:

I want to render `"/catalogo?q=text&orden=_namedesc"` and I recibe `/catalogo?q=bosi&amp;orden=_namedesc`

```
...
<script>
        const CATALOG_URL = '@CatalogService.getCatalogUrl()';
</script>
```

```cs
namespace Web.Services
{
    public class CatalogService: ICatalogService
    {
        public string getCatalogUrl()
        {
            return "/catalogo?q=text&orden=_namedesc";
        }
    }
}
```

How Can I render the text whitout encoding?.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try with `@Html.Raw()` inside the script tag? like this

```
<script>
const CATALOG_URL = "@Html.Raw(CatalogService.getCatalogUrl())"
</script>
```